# Is there a way in javascript to know what hours will be 9 am in a specified timezone?

Tags: javascript

Well I need to know what hours will be 9am in user time compared with my timezone.

like:

> I'm from Brazil 9 am GMT -0300

i.e: some user from 'Cairo' access my website then I need to know when will be 9 am in his time compared with my time 'Cairo' gmt is +0200.

Is there a way to do it with Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for `getTimezoneOffset()` method
(see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp):

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

`n` will be the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time in minutes.

More comprehensive guide here: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/.

EDIT:
Oh, I forgot about the future time part. In that case, it should be enough to create custom date instance using one of the extended constructors:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

It can be used to determine the timezone difference at that time.
You can easily determine the offset `o` at some time, and the final offset at the specified time is either `o`,  `o + 60` or  `o - 60`, which can be easily checked with `getTimezoneOffset()` on the `Date` object created with the extended constructor.

In the worst-case scenario, you might have to do 2-3 calculation steps to determine your final result.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout: [javascript timezone converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539561/javascript-timezone-converter), there's an already open discussion there about your inquired topic.