# Countdown down to specific date and time, on US EST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery-timer plugin for a countdown box. I have an interface where people can set it up to countdown to a specific time, but I need that specific time to countdown to that time in EST.

For example, if they enter 07/03/2016 10:00 am, it needs to countdown to  07/03/2016 10:00 am EST, no matter where they are. How can I do this?

Here is the countdown timer I'm using: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539561/javascript-timezone-converter

Comment: Isn't that going to be a bit confusing for people in other countries/timezones?